# How would I auto select a drop down picker view in a UIWebView without using .selectedIndex =?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview, element

I have used `[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptString@"document.getElementById('ELEMENTNAME').value = 'NAME OF VALUE I WANT'"];`

But this does not work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please write the entire question in the question, don't use the subject as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selectedIndex property instead.

For example, if you want to select the 3rd option, use

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENTNAME').selectedIndex = 2 //Index of the option.
```

For the 6th option, use

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENTNAME').selectedIndex = 5 //Index of the option.
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already done this, and it works, however I need it to select the option based on the name of the option rather than the order. Thanks